# How to force SSIS to read backslash as a single sign

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I would like to create an SSIS package which would repeat some actions for a lot of different servers.

To achieve that I created an table `dbo.serverlist` which stores server names. At the first step of my package I use execute sql task, which reads that table and saves list of servers to object type  variable - `ServerList`. Than I have Foreach Loop container in which I iterate through elements of `ServerList`. Each element is saved to string type variable `ServerName`. Within that loop I pull data from each server.

My problem is that sometimes I connect to default and sometimes to named instance of SQL server. So `ServerName` for named instances should be equal to `[Server Name]\[Instance Name]`. But I have noticed that SSIS doubles backslash and for such servers it sets that variable to `[Server Name]\\[Instance Name]`.

Connection is working fine (which is a little bit surprising for me). But queries which I use to set bookmarks are invalid. As I need to use something like `select bookmark from dbo.serverlist where server = ?`   where parameter is mapped to `ServerName`.

Could you please advise how to force SSIS to read `\` correctly?

Comment: It depends on where in SSIS you are trying to do this, could be different solution for different locations.  Can you post some code/examples so we can see where/how you are doing it now specifically

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution for you.

- Add a new SSIS variable to be passed as a parameter to a query.
- Add SSIS Expression Task just before executing the `select bookmark from dbo.serverlist where server = ?`. Its expression should remove one backslash from the `'\\'`.
- Use new variable with a single backslash as a parameter to a query.

Useful link: [Handling Escape Sequences in SSIS Expression String Literals](https://devinknightsql.com/2010/01/27/handling-escape-sequences-in-ssis-expression-string-literals/)